# MySQL UNION creating strange result

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm trying to combine the data of two tables in order to get the total lead count by state. However, for some reason it's taking all leads from table_1 and putting it under TX (Texas). Both queries work correctly when separate, but not when combined with a union.

```
TX  197 (This is the combined total of all leads in table_1)
CA  102 (This is the total for table_2. Does not include table_1)
TX  48  (This is the total for table_2. Does not include table_1)
FL  37  (This is the total for table_2. Does not include table_1)
MO  35  ...
NY  25  ...
etc. etc.
```

Here's my query...

```
SELECT state, count(*) AS cnt FROM `table_1` WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT state, count(*) AS cnt FROM `table_2` WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL 
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some parenthesis, so the group by executes after the union, and move the count out

```
    select state, count(*) AS cnt FROM 
        (SELECT state FROM `table_1` WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT state  FROM `table_2` WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL
        ) T
        GROUP BY state
        ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` only applies to the *second* subquery.  That is not what you intend.

In most databases your query would generate an error.  I think you want:

```
SELECT state, SUM(cnt) as cnt
FROM ((SELECT state, count(*) AS cnt
       FROM `table_1`
       WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT state, count(*) AS cnt
       FROM `table_2`
       WHERE submission_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND unk IS NULL 
       GROUP BY state
      )
     ) s
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY SUM(cnt) DESC;
```

Doing the `GROUP BY` in each subquery is optional.  However, the performance of `GROUP BY` grows faster than linearly.  So, two smaller `GROUP BY`s is usually faster than one bigger one -- even with the outer aggregation.